# Cannot install OpenCV using pip3

Tags: python, opencv, ssl

When I tried to install OpenCV on Raspberry Pi for object detection, I got this error:

> pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available
>   open ssl version -OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018)

I am using Python 2.7 as global and installed all packages for OpenCV.

Pip version: `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)`

I used `pip3 install opencv-python` to install OpenCV.

This is the error:

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting opencv-python
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/opencv-python/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not fetch URL https://www.piwheels.org/simple/opencv-python/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-python
```

Comment: Can you configure it without the ssl?

Comment: how can i do that please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't install OpenCV on Raspberry Pi without building it yourself. This is why you get the error `No matching distribution found for opencv-python`. You have to build it yourself on the Raspberry Pi. The most recent versions also use Python 3, which you will need to use but should be included in the Rasbian image. Try `python3 --version` to find out.

There is a detailed guide here you can follow to build and install OpenCV: https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/

The website above also has a script you can download and use to install it more easily.

Comment: i cant install any packages using pip3 command and it gives me this ssl error